# Computed style doesn't return computed width of an element

Tags: javascript, css

In order to have the timeline line the same width as the list of horizontal entries, I thought I could set the ordered list to `max-content`, then set the computed width of the list to the line. However the value assigned to `computedTimelineStyle.width` is zero.

Is there a workaround for what I want to achieve?

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  let yearKeys = Object.keys(timeEntries);
  let timeline = document.getElementsByClassName("timeline")[0];
  let timelineLine = document.getElementsByClassName("timeline_line")[0];
  let computedTimelineStyle = window.getComputedStyle(timeline);
  console.log(computedTimelineStyle.width);
  timelineLine.style.width = computedTimelineStyle.width;

  for (const yearKey in yearKeys) {
    if (yearKeys.hasOwnProperty(yearKey)) {
      const year = yearKeys[yearKey];
      let yearElement = document.createElement("li");
      yearElement.innerHTML = year;
      timeline.appendChild(yearElement);
    }
  }
});
```

Log:

```
0px main.js:93:11
```

```js
let focussed = { year: false, month: false };

let months = {
  1: {
    title: "January",
    days: 31
  },
  2: {
    title: "Febuary",
    days: 28
  },
  3: {
    title: "March",
    days: 31
  },
  4: {
    title: "April",
    days: 30
  },
  5: {
    title: "May",
    days: 31
  },
  6: {
    title: "June",
    days: 30
  },
  7: {
    title: "July",
    days: 31
  },
  8: {
    title: "August",
    days: 31
  },
  9: {
    title: "September",
    days: 30
  },
  10: {
    title: "October",
    days: 31
  },
  11: {
    title: "November",
    days: 30
  },
  12: {
    title: "December",
    days: 31
  }
};

let timeEntries = {
  2019: {
    // 1: {
    //   2: {
    //     title: "Test Title",
    //     desc:
    //       "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque at ligula varius, mattis urna sed, auctor tellus. Aliquam fringilla gravida imperdiet. Aliquam elementum vulputate quam. Pellentesque imperdiet neque sit amet tellus finibus tempor. Quisque nunc est, viverra vel maximus non, fringilla in nulla. Morbi vestibulum turpis et est luctus, in tempus sapien iaculis. Sed in nisi in leo luctus finibus. Donec mattis eleifend auctor."
    //   }
    // }
  },
  2018: {},
  2017: {},
  2016: {},
  2015: {},
  2014: {},
  2013: {},
  2012: {},
  2011: {},
  2010: {},
  2009: {},
  2008: {},
  2007: {},
  2006: {},
  2005: {},
  2004: {},
  2003: {},
  2002: {},
  2001: {},
  2000: {},
  1999: {},
  1998: {},
  1997: {},
};

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  let yearKeys = Object.keys(timeEntries);
  let timeline = document.getElementsByClassName("timeline")[0];
  let timelineLine = document.getElementsByClassName("timeline_line")[0];
  let computedTimelineStyle = window.getComputedStyle(timeline);
  console.log(computedTimelineStyle.width);
  timelineLine.style.width = computedTimelineStyle.width;

  for (const yearKey in yearKeys) {
    if (yearKeys.hasOwnProperty(yearKey)) {
      const year = yearKeys[yearKey];
      let yearElement = document.createElement("li");
      yearElement.innerHTML = year;
      timeline.appendChild(yearElement);
    }
  }
});
```

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:500&display=swap");
.timeline_box {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 50%;
  background: lightslategrey;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 10%;
  display: grid;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
  position: relative; }

.timeline_wrapper {
  width: max-content;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 200px; }

.timeline_line {
  z-index: 1;
  width: inherit;
  height: 20px;
  margin-top: 90px;
  margin-bottom: 90px;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 41%, #fd2600 60%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 55%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%); }

.timeline {
  z-index: 2;
  list-style: none;
  width: max-content;
  margin-top: 80px;
  margin-bottom: 80px; }
  .timeline > li {
    float: left;
    background: lightslategrey;
    padding-left: 7px;
    padding-right: 7px;
    margin-left: 266px;
    font-size: 2rem;
    border-radius: 5px; }
    .timeline > li:nth-child(1) {
      margin-left: 0; }

button {
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  color: black;
  margin: auto; }

html,
body,
element,
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif; }
```

```html
    <div class="timeline_box">
      <div class="timeline_wrapper">
        <ol id="entries" class="timeline">
        </ol>
        <div class="timeline_line"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

PS: I know the entries go off the box, that is the point. In order to achieve what I want to I need to have the entries exceed the limitations of the gray box, along with the line. In my local web server the entries are actually hidden.

Comment: What kind of element is timeline?  What is it's width when inspected in the browser?

Comment: @ThomasPreston 7898.5px, however, this number will change as I add more entries. The timeline is meant to adapt to the number of entries in the JSON object.

Comment: Well you need to readjust the width after adding an element. Because has you do it now you just add the initial width which is 0 and never change it again.

Comment: I'm assuming "timeline" is an <ol>.  At the time this code is called, has it been populated with <li> elements?  I'm wondering if this has to do with the timing in regards to doing this on DOMContentLoaded.

Comment: @MihaiT Yeah, I know I need to do that but I don't know how.

Comment: @ThomasPreston You are correct. The reason I employed DOMContentLoaded is that I assumed that event would be invoked once all the elements have been loaded.

Comment: You should really provide a proper [mre] here, right now this question lacks context.

Comment: your elements are loaded. But they are added to html of the element later on. And that event is not triggered.

Comment: @04FS There you go.

Comment: @MihaiT Oh? What even would I need to get the computed value after it has been calculated. Afaik there is no 'ready' event like there in in Jquery.

Comment: you just need to check the width of the `timeline` after the elements are added to the HTML. Your code is synchronous so just initiate the `computedTimelineStyle` variable value after the for loop. Check my answer below. If that's now what you wanted, please leave a comment there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your elements are loaded to the page but you need to check the computed width of the `timeLine` after the addition of the elements.

So you just need to add the `let computedTimelineStyle = window.getComputedStyle(timeline);` after the for loop.

```js
let timeEntries = {
  2019: {
  },
  2018: {},
  2017222: {},
  2016: {},
  2015: {},
  2014: {},
  2013: {},
  2012: {},
  2011: {},
  2010: {},
  2009: {},
  2008: {},
  2007: {},
  2006: {},
  2005: {},
  2004: {},
  2003: {},
  2002: {},
  2001: {},
  2000222224444: {},
  1999: {},
  1998: {},
  1997: {},
};

const timeline = document.getElementsByClassName("timeline")[0];
const yearKeys = Object.keys(timeEntries);

for (const yearKey  in yearKeys) {
 const year = yearKeys[yearKey];
  const yearElement = document.createElement("li");
  yearElement.innerHTML = year;
  timeline.appendChild(yearElement);
}

let computedTimelineStyle = window.getComputedStyle(timeline);
console.log(computedTimelineStyle.width);
```

```css
.first {
 width: max-content;
  background: red;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
```

```html
<ul class="timeline first">

</ul>
<ul class="timeline">

</ul>
<ul class="timeline">

</ul>
<ul class="timeline">

</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you must let some time to the browser to calculate everything. Try to timeout your pickup code some ms after DOMContentLoaded to check if it works for you.

If it does not work, try to use dom object offsetWidth property ( https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetWidth ). It should return the width in px.